# Local variable already defined when using 'is' keyword - goes against language reference

Tags: c#

As per the C# language reference at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is

```
expr is type varname
```

> If expr is `true` and `is` is used with an `if` statement, varname is assigned and has **local scope within the `if` statement only**.

```
if(first_object is Folder folder)
{
    // ...
}

if(second_object is Folder folder) // ERROR!
{
    // ...
}
```

The above produces the following error:

> A local variable or function named 'folder' is already defined in this scope

Why can't I reuse the variable name when it's supposed to be local only to each `if` statement?

Comment: Given `folder` can be assigned **after** the first `if`, then it clearly has function level scope.

Comment: @mjwills But that surely couldn't have been the intended behavior. Why would anyone re-use such a variable? You can't re-use the variables defined within a `for` loop, for example.

Comment: It is documented and intended, as per my answer below. Yes, it is confusing. :) Why don't loops work the same way? Because they create a new scope (which `if .. is` does not).

Comment: @S.McPharlin *Why would anyone re-use such a variable?* For example: `if(!(obj is Something something)) { throw new Exception(); } /* here you can use something */`.

Comment: I originally marked this as a duplicate. After further reflection, I think the duplicate is **not** the same issue as discussed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching):

```
public static double ComputeAreaModernIs(object shape)
{
    if (shape is Square s)
        return s.Side * s.Side;
    else if (shape is Circle c)
        return c.Radius * c.Radius * Math.PI;
    else if (shape is Rectangle r)
        return r.Height * r.Length;
    // elided
    throw new ArgumentException(
        message: "shape is not a recognized shape",
        paramName: nameof(shape));
}
```

> Let's examine both of those rules in detail, beginning with scope. The
>   variable c is in scope only in the else branch of the first if
>   statement. The variable s is in scope in the method
>   ComputeAreaModernIs. That's because each branch of an if statement
>   establishes a separate scope for variables. However, the if statement
>   itself does not. **That means variables declared in the if statement are**
>   **in the same scope as the if statement (the method in this case.)** This
>   behavior is not specific to pattern matching, but is the defined
>   behavior for variable scopes and if and else statements.

Is it weird, and confusing (that `if` doesn't set up a scope, but `else` does)? Yes, yes it is. :)

Comment: It would be nice to get some ECMA specs on this, but alas they aren't available for 7.0 yet. anyway you beat me to that blurb, upvote

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to understand that If is not scope limiting syntax.
2. Means whatever out side of If statement are available.
3. It will limit the scope for variable that declare inside If loop but not in If Condition it self.